# SQL Server - distinct combination of three columns- order doesn't matter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get count of 3 columns values combination by each combination in SQL Server. How do I get this?

Ex.

```css
Row    P1   P2   P3
 1     3    10   20
 2     4    15   29
 3     8    10   16
 4     15    4   29
 5     10   20    3

Output Should be:
3  10  20  - 2
4  15  29  - 2
8  10  16  - 1
```

Thanks,

Comment: What the column 4 come from?

Comment: Basically I need to compare row by row for combination (order doesn't matter) of 3 column P1, P2, P3. I could have use "select distinct P1,P2,P3, count(*) from tblName group by P1,P2,P3" if order matters. In my case, order doesn't matter.

Comment: @Tony..Column 4 is the count value!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### option 1 -

#### cross apply, for xml path, group by.

```
select      vals,count (*) as cnt
from        t cross apply (select ' ' + cast (p as varchar(10)) from (values (p1),(p2),(p3)) as t(p) order by p for xml path('')) v (vals)
group by    vals
```

---

```
vals        cnt
 3 10 20    2
 4 15 29    2
 8 10 16    1
```

#### option 2 -

#### xquery, group by

```
select      vals
           ,count (*) as cnt

from       (select      cast ((cast ('' as xml)).query('for $i in (sql:column("p1"),sql:column("p2"),sql:column("p3")) order by $i return $i') as varchar(max)) as vals

            from        t
            ) t

group by    vals
;
```

---

```
vals        cnt
-------     ---
3 10 20     2
4 15 29     2
8 10 16     1
```

---

#### option 3 -

#### Unpivot, row_number, Pivot.

```
select      [1],[2],[3],count (*) as cnt
from       (select      row,p,row_number () over (partition by row order by p) as n
            from        t unpivot (p for col in (p1,p2,p3)) upv
            ) t pivot (max(p) for n in ([1],[2],[3])) pv
group by    [1],[2],[3]
```

---

```
1   2   3   cnt
--- --- --- ---
3   10  20  2
4   15  29  2
8   10  16  1
```

#### option 4 -

#### offset n rows, group by.

```
select      [1],[2],[3],count(*) as cnt

from       (select      (select p from (values (p1),(p2),(p3))as t(p) order by p offset 0 rows fetch first 1 row only)  as [1]
                       ,(select p from (values (p1),(p2),(p3))as t(p) order by p offset 1 rows fetch first 1 row only)  as [2]
                       ,(select p from (values (p1),(p2),(p3))as t(p) order by p offset 2 rows fetch first 1 row only)  as [3]

            from        t
            ) t

group by    [1],[2],[3]
```

---

```
1   2   3   cnt
--- --- --- ---
3   10  20  2
4   15  29  2
8   10  16  1
```

Comment: Thank you guys! I will apply the suggested solutions to implement.

Comment: I love your answer but on SO using a 10 character indent (or no indents) is really hard to read since there is a limited width.  -- Please consider formatting your code!

Comment: @Dudu, can you explain option 1? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Oh, this is a pain.

```
select p_1, p_2, p_3, count(*) as cnt
from t cross apply
     (select max(case when seqnum = 1 then p end) as p_1,
             max(case when seqnum = 2 then p end) as p_2,
             max(case when seqnum = 3 then p end) as p_3
      from (select p, row_number() over (order by p) as seqnum
            from (values (p1), (p2), (p3)
                 ) v(p)
           ) rp
     ) rp
group by p_1, p_2, p_3;
```

What is this doing?  The `cross apply` first unpivots the values onto separate rows.  Then it enumerates the values (using `row_number()`, ordering by the value.  This generates a sequence number, which is used for pivoting the values -- in order.

Finally, with the values in order on each row, we can aggregate the values to get the counts you are asking for.

Comment: This is very cute but I think 3 case statements might be easier to understand

Comment: @Hogan, would you still think that if we would have to deal with 4 values? 5 values?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz - yes this scales much better of course -- it is also easier to use this template if you need to create dynamic SQL.

Comment: @Hogan, you are right, but this is not the interesting part. Try to think how the 3 (or 4 or 5) case statements will look like

Comment: @Hogan . . . And try writing the `case` statements to take `NULL` values into account.

Answer (score 1):

This is another approach where in using a `case` expression the least of the 3 values is assigned c1, the second least c2 and the greatest c3. Thereafter,it is just a grouping operation.

```
select c1,c2,c3,count(*) 
from (
select case when p1<=p2 and p1<=p3 then p1
        when p2<=p1 and p2<=p3 then p2
        when p3<=p1 and p3<=p2 then p3 end c1,
   case when p1 between p2 and p3 or p1 between p3 and p2 then p1
        when p2 between p1 and p3 or p2 between p3 and p1 then p2
        when p3 between p1 and p2 or p3 between p2 and p1 then p3 end c2,
   case when p2<=p1 and p3<=p1 then p1
        when p1<=p2 and p3<=p2 then p2
        when p1<=p3 and p2<=p3 then p3 end c3
from t
) x
group by c1,c2,c3
```

**[`Sample Demo`](http://rextester.com/VHYN15508)**

The assumption here is that none of p1,p2,p3 values is null. If they can be `null` , use `coalesce` in the case expression depending on how you want to treat those rows for counting.